# How to see Production Behavior while Testing Everyplay

Tags: everyplay

The Everyplay Integration guide mentions that there's differing behavior between the development and production environment (https://developers.everyplay.com/doc/Everyplay-integration-design-guide#tip-3-enable-facecam-for-live-commentary). Is there a way to turn on the Production version while testing?

I'd like to see what my players will eventually see to make sure there are no last second bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mention of live facecam restrictions in the integration best practices document is just that, a best practice. There is no technical restriction to recording the FaceCam automatically every session, but our guidelines restrict this - the feature needs to be opt-in only!

Live Facecam can also be used as a tool for QA to allow testers to record the comments on the go, and therefore it may be useful to automatically record the forward-facing camera on each session, but this is not an option for AppStore distributed games. Therefore we make the distinction in the docs about the differences in integration in development vs. production, but as said, there is no technical difference here.